# Конфликт сервера nginx

Tags: nginx

После установки сертификата SSL от Let’s Encrypt через cerbot.
Nginx перестал запускать сайт при проверке sudo nginx -t выдает ошибку `[warn] conflicting server name "mydomen.ru" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

````
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomen.ru www.mydomen.ru ;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /root/mysite/ksyshev/project/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Значит в каком-то другом файле у вас дублируется server_name mydomen.ru, ищите

Comment: nginx -T выведет весь конфиг